# How are Fat Calories in meat calculated?

Tags: body-fat, calories

There is standard 73% lean and more expensive 93% lean ground beef.

When the 73% lean ground beef is cooked, a lot of fat melts off and gets poured out.

When the 93% lean ground beef is cooked, not much fat melts off and nothing gets poured out.

By pouring off the melted fat, am I not left with ground beef that is leaner than 73%?

The same goes for bacon. The package of raw bacon shows high fat content, but whenever I cook that bacon, the grease is poured off.

My best guess is that the nutritional labels on raw meats display the included fat of that grease that is not used.

How do I address these calories from fat in meat products?

Comment: You probably could have gotten a good answer to this on Cooking.SE because knowing the actual fat % of the raw product they're working with is essential to a cook. They don't care what's left after cooking because it depends on how you cook it. In short, if you want a dry, tasteless hamburger then use the expensive 93% ground beef. If you want a good, juicy hamburger then use the cheaper 73% ground beef.

Comment: @CareyGregory - there are hundreds of SE sites. Cooking did not show up in my list: https://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 2):

For the US, see [9 CFR § 317.345](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/9/317.345)

> The nutrition label data for products covered in paragraphs (a)(1) and (a)(2) must be based on either the raw or cooked edible portions of meat cuts with external cover fat at trim levels reflecting current marketing practices. If data are based on cooked portions, the methods used to cook the products must be specified and for products covered in paragraphs (a)(1) and (a)(2) must be those which do not add nutrients from other ingredients such as flour, breading, and salt. Additional nutritional data may be presented on an optional basis for the raw or cooked edible portions of the separable lean of meat cuts.

Some of the other sections and references may also be relevant, but the parts that seem most relevant to your question are "*must be based on either the raw or cooked edible portion*" and "*If data are based on cooked portions, the methods used to cook the products must be specified*". You'll have to check the labels that you're reading: if they don't say how it's cooked, it's based on raw.

You could substitute reference categories mentioned in the statue from the USDA, e.g. https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/?query=bacon - these can also be used for labeling.